# Wine PATH through command line and not persistent

Tags: path, wine

I know I can change my wine PATH through regedit, but I actually need to change the PATH just for a single run.

For example, I have my software called *frontend.exe*, this depends on *example/mylib.dll*, I need to invoke frontend.exe with *example/* on PATH. But I may not set this on the registry be cause this configuration is just for this application, not for every wine application...

Comment: Can you just set it in an environment variable before your run `frontend.exe`?

Comment: You mean through a .bat file?

Comment: Would be easier if there were a WINEPATH enviroment variable or command line argument because I am calling my wine application from inside a shell script.

Comment: André, did you manage to solve this (now rather old) problem?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Ironically, wine supports the WINEPATH variable. If, in your Unix Shell, you export WINEPATH, once you launch wine it will use this to populate the PATH environment variable inside wine.

Comment: Is that documented somewhere? I cannot find a reference.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner I could not find anything on Google regarding WINEPATH. But I just tested it and it works as expected. You have to provide the paths in the Windows format (\ instead of /), however, as wine will not convert it.

Comment: Indeed, it works. Would you mind turning this into an answer?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Done.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wine supports the WINEPATH variable. If, in your Unix Shell, you export WINEPATH, once you launch wine it will use this to populate the PATH environment variable inside wine.

Example:

```
$ WINEPATH=anything\\it//willNotBeParsed wine cmd
Wine CMD Version 5.1.2600 (1.6.2)

C:\>echo %PATH%
anything\it//willNotBeParsed;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\system32\wbem
```

Comment: I know this is old, But I am stuck exporting java jre to wine, I set `WINEPATH` to `/usr/lib/openjdk-8/bin` and it went as it is in wine's %PATH% i.e. the unix path not the windows compatible path name. How can I convert it to windows compatible path as environment variable.

Comment: @AbhinavKulshreshtha You can use the `winepath` command line tool, e.g. `winepath -w /usr/lib/openjdk-8/bin`.